# For importing Scribe OAuth library on android, build.gradle built successfully but throwing error on running the app

Tags: android, gradle, scribe

I have put **scribe-1.3.7.jar** file on my libs folder and 
I have this `build.gradle` file to import Scribe `OAuth` library -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.example.com.scribetest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'org.scribe:scribe:1.3.7'
```

The `build.gradle` file is building successfully but on running the app its showing an error -

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 1

**Whats wrong in the `build.gradle` ?**